# Parsing multiple words at the end of a string - regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Basically I have a line out of a log that I've parsed peices of information out of. I can't seem to figure out how to extract a chunk of text from the end of the line. For example:

```
2012-06-25 16:19:42,777 [main]  INFO  ControllerServiceImpl.java (line 72) Starting controller service
```

"**Starting controller service**"

I have used regex's to take out the date and other information, but I'm looking for a way to take out all words after the parenthetical closing the line number to the end of the string (bolded)

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with positive lookbehind ?<=. Pattern:

```
(?<=\))(\s?\w)+$
```

If you have more than one line, don't forget to add flag 'm' - multiline flag.

Comment: What does the "\" after the lookbehind represent? When I apply the expression to the whole log it is only picking out the lines "Starting controller service". I'm very confused by this.

Comment: \ is escaping ). So basically it means 'If there is ) before some words and then end of a string/line'

Comment: Oh wow. How did I miss that. I'm still a bit confused as to why, even when enabling multiline, the word Starting is selected as a opposed to everything following the parenthetical. http://regexr.com?31kit

Comment: Oh, If you want all the text after (line blabla) you should use patteren like this: `(?<=\))(\s?.)+?$` (I assumed only word characters, so I changed to . - any character and made + non-greedy). http://regexr.com?31kjo

Comment: Could I perhaps have a few minutes of your time? I have some more questions about regular expressions. Maybe via email or IM?